# Schwarz space $S(\mathbb{R})$ is dense inside $L_p(\mathbb{R})$-spaces

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces, schwartz-space

I was wondering why the schwarz functions $S(\mathbb{R})$ are dense inside the $L_p(\mathbb{R})$ spaces and I was reading [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1589039/340973), but I don't understand why the $g_t$ are in $S(\mathbb{R})$. Could someone explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the following first:

> The convolution with any function with compact support is given by an integral on a compact interval.

So now you can establish the second point:

> The convolution with any $C^\infty$ function given by an integral on a compact interval gives a $C^\infty$ function (basically you can take the derivatives inside).

Comment: The first point is clear, if I consider $supp(g)\subset [-R,R]$, then $f \ast g(x) =\int_{-R}^{R}f(x-t)g(t)dt$ but then why can I take the derivative inside, since I don't even know that $f$ is differentiable no? I just know it is in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ right?

Comment: You know that $f*g=g*f$.

Comment: Okay, I get it now. Nice trick